# How can I add files in separate folders to a ZIP archive?

Tags: ant

I am trying to add 3 diferent TXT files to one ZIP file.
Those 3 TXT files are in separate folders but I have their path.

In the end, I just want a ZIP file with those 3 files in it.

Also, if one of them does not exist, will it include the 2 other ones or will it throw an exception and create no ZIP file?

Answer (score 1):

```
<zip destfile="your.zip">
    <fileset dir="path1" includes="file1.txt"/>
    <fileset dir="path2" includes="file2.txt"/>
    <fileset dir="path3" includes="file3.txt"/>
</zip>
```

You can include multiple [filesets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) into a single [zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) file.

If the path doesn't exist, you'll get an error.  If a file doesn't exist, it doesn't care.  If none of the files exist, you'll get a warning.